# Textarea inside div, getting changed value

Tags: jquery

i have textarea and lot of other HTML elements inside one div, like this:

```
 <div id="holder">
 <textarea id="txt">Some text</textarea>
 <img src="/someurl/test.png" />
 <div class="test">Blah</div>
 </div>
```

When i try to get all html inside "holder" div, with code below, it works well. BUT if i change textarea value, and try to get html again, value of textarea is still "Some text", not new text. How to get new, updated text?

Here is how i get html of "holder":

```
 $("#submit").click(function(){
    alert($("#holder").html() ); 
 });
```

And here is jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/zmL7k/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update the textarea html manually:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $("#txt").html(function() {
        return this.value;
    });
    alert($("#holder").html());
});​
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But one more question: in my original code, i have lot of textareas with different id's (they are in thsi format: some_div_12, some_div_34 etc.). They all have same class, but i know that matching by class is lot slower, so is there way to match by div?
EDIT: sorry, i just realised that i can match it by tag name : $("textarea"). Tnx for your help :)

Comment: @SomeoneS `$( "textarea", "#holder")` I guess. This will select the textareas that are specifically under `"#holder"`